# Why a Content control is split in several runs?

Tags: c#, openxml

I got an application that deal with word documents using open xml.

So, when I create my word documents, I add some content control.

To do it, I was selecting a text, and then click on 'create a content control' on the word developer panel.

The thing is, it seems it is cutting my text into several different run.

So, When I want to replace the text in a content control, It will not replace all the text, because it has been split.

Somebody has any explanations?

How can I fix this?

For informations, this is how I get a sdtElement :

```
SdtBlock sdtElement = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Descendants<SdtBlock>()
                       .Where(element =>
                           element.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<SdtAlias>() != null &&
                           element.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<SdtAlias>().Val == "CADRE").SingleOrDefault();
                    if (sdtElement != null)
                    {
                        sdtElement.Descendants<Text>().FirstOrDefault().Text = "Some text";
}
```

Is there a way to avoid this split in my content control. Because it shouldn't happend, as the text is select as one before I create the control.

**edit : As JasonPlustext says, the good question is : How can I be sure that this split will not be happening?**

here is the xml :

```
<w:sdtContent>
      <w:sdt>
        <w:sdtPr>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:b />
            <w:sz w:val="26" />
          </w:rPr>
          <w:alias w:val="CADRE" />
          <w:tag w:val="CADRE" />
          <w:id w:val="-535731825" />
          <w:placeholder>
            <w:docPart w:val="DefaultPlaceholder_1082065158" />
          </w:placeholder>
          <w:text />
        </w:sdtPr>
        <w:sdtEndPr />
        <w:sdtContent>
          <w:p w:rsidR="00E07C25" w:rsidRDefault="00EB5705">
            <w:pPr>
              <w:pBdr>
                <w:top w:val="single" w:color="auto" w:sz="12" w:space="1" />
                <w:left w:val="single" w:color="auto" w:sz="12" w:space="1" />
                <w:bottom w:val="single" w:color="auto" w:sz="12" w:space="1" />
                <w:right w:val="single" w:color="auto" w:sz="12" w:space="1" />
              </w:pBdr>
              <w:shd w:val="pct20" w:color="auto" w:fill="auto" />
              <w:ind w:left="567" w:right="566" />
              <w:jc w:val="center" />
              <w:rPr>
                <w:b />
                <w:sz w:val="26" />
              </w:rPr>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
              <w:rPr>
                <w:b />
                <w:sz w:val="26" />
              </w:rPr>
              <w:t>$CA</w:t>
            </w:r>
            <w:r w:rsidR="004943F1">
              <w:rPr>
                <w:b />
                <w:sz w:val="26" />
              </w:rPr>
              <w:t>DRE$</w:t>
            </w:r>
          </w:p>
        </w:sdtContent>
      </w:sdt>
    </w:sdtContent>
```

Also I tried deleting the text, and rewrite it, and this time, it doesn't had split the text.

The thing is, I got a lot of documents, so i a lot of work to rewrite them all.

Is there a simpliest solution?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure the run wasn't split before you added the content control?  Please post the resulting XML.  In general, there is never a guarantee that a run won't be split arbitrarily.  So the question is, when is it safe to rely on that not happening.

Comment: @JasonPlutext inded, I'm not sure, but why a simple word, would be split? and indeed the good question is, how can I be sure that this will not happening.

Comment: @JasonPlutext add the xml (only one sdtContent).

Comment: @JasonPlutext Maybe the solution is to delete, all the run nodes, that are not the first, so there will be no problem in the text.

Comment: It looks like you are putting variables ($CADRE) in content controls.  Why not get rid of the variables, and use content control data binding (via XPath) to an XML document containing your values?